# unknown field "capabilities" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSecurityContext (running tshark in a container/k8s pod)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tshark

I have build a docker image containing `tshark` (its an image I am going to use for doing various manual debugging from a kubernetes pod).

I have deployed a container in kubernetes running that image. But when I access the container and try to run `tshark` I get:

```
$ kubectl exec myapp-cbd49f587-w2swx -it bash
root@myapp-cbd49f587-w2swx:/# tshark -ni any -f "test.host" -w sample.pcap -F libpcap
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'any'
tshark: cap_set_proc() fail return: Operation not permitted
```

Googling that error:

https://www.weave.works/blog/container-capabilities-kubernetes/
https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/policy/container-capabilities/

it seems I need to configure a `securityContext` for my container/pod. In my deployment.yaml I have added:

```
  containers:
     ...
  securityContext:
    capabilities:
      add:
        - NET_ADMIN
```

But when I apply that deployment I get:

```
error: error validating "deployment.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.securityContext): unknown field "capabilities" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSecurityContext; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Adding `--validate=false` removes the error but also means the securityContext is ignored.

What is preventing me from setting:

```
  securityContext:
    capabilities:
      add:
        - NET_ADMIN
```

Based on the guides I have found this should be fine.

I have also looked at (looks to be non free):

https://sysdig.com/blog/tracing-in-kubernetes-kubectl-capture-plugin/

so probably the right way is to use some tool like that ([ksniff](https://github.com/eldadru/ksniff)) or setup a  [sidecar container](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/02/27/sidecars-analyze-debug-network-traffic-kubernetes-pod/). But I am still curious to why I get the above error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking specifically to the error, you posted only part of your manifest and looking to this we can see that you put `securityContext:` in the same level as `containers:`:

```
  containers:
     ...
  securityContext:
    capabilities:
      add:
        - NET_ADMIN
```

It should be under `containers:` as as written in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/):

> To add or remove Linux capabilities for a Container, include the
> `capabilities` field in the `securityContext` section of the Container
> manifest.

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: security-context-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: security-context-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sec-ctx-4
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_ADMIN
```

Comment: But isn't securityContext configurable at the pod level as well? per https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod @u123

Comment: Check [Yasir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4703720/yasir-mir) answer, it's only possible at container level.

Comment: Great catch! Confusingly though, only `capabilities` is so strict that it will cause an error if your put it on the level of `containers`, while other settings like `runAsUser` will actually work even then... Note also the reverse, i.e. `capabilities.drop`

Answer (score 5):

Linux capabilities can be added only at container level security-context, not at the pod level.

Not obvious here but see that the section on adding capabilities only mentions adding it to the container:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container

Comment: Great addition!

Comment: True! The "capabilities" is clearly not among the list of fields for podSecurityContext V1: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core